# unity-control-center Could not find settings panel "printers"

Tags: unity, software-center, printing, 16.10

I have upgraded some days ago to 16.10, but today I found that panel printers is missing from unity-control-center.

In the console:

```
$ unity-control-center printers

** (unity-control-center:15538): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "printers"
```

How can I add another printer? Or fix the System settings console?

Answer (score 0):

I installed this:
sudo apt install system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome

And then Printers came back.